# Accessing a subelement in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

In Flash CS5 I have a button with an instance name "btn", which is made up of movie clips with instance names "mv1" and "mv2".

The question is: can I use gotoAndStop or something similar on the movie clips inside the button from the stage in which the button is instantiated. In pseudocode:

btn.mv1.gotoAndStop(3);
btn.mv2.gotoAndStop(7);

This is likely to be  a very basic question, but the one I could not find any information on in the last half an hour.

Comment: Didn't really work out with buttons, so swapped it for a movie and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably yes, if btn happens to be a MovieClip. For (almost?) any other display class (DisplayObject, DisplayObjectContainer, Sprite etc) this will fail in compilation.

If your compiler refuses to run your code, try this:

```
var mv1:MovieClip = btn.getChildByName("mv1") as MovieClip;
mv1.gotoAndStop(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

`btn.mv1.gotoAndStop(3);` will work perfectly fine.